# Convert pd.get_dummies result to df.str.get_dummies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have quite a big dataframe in a shape like

```
animal    ids
cat       1,3,4
dog       1,2,4
hamster   5        
dolphin   3,5
```

It has about 60k rows, and ids column has over 100k comma separated integers for many rows, and most have over 10k ids. Trying to run

```
u = df["ids"].str.get_dummies(",")
```

so that I can calculate jaccard index, but due to the data size, it crashes with Memory error, because series.str.get_dummies() is using Int64 as dtype, and there is no way to change it, at least I don't how, as str.get_dummies() doesn't have dtype parameter.

So I tried to run instead

```
u = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=["ids"], dtype=np.uint8)
```

which worked, but it produces totally different result.

For example, if we run `u = df["ids"].str.get_dummies(",")` on the example above, it produces

```
   1  2  3  4  5
0  1  0  1  1  0
1  1  1  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0  1
3  0  0  1  0  1
```

and if we run `u = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=["ids"], dtype=np.uint8)`, it gives

```
    animal  ids_1,2,4  ids_1,3,4  ids_3,5  ids_5
0      cat          0          1        0      0
1      dog          1          0        0      0
2  hamster          0          0        0      1
3  dolphin          0          0        1      0
```

Is there a way either setting the dtype to uint8 for `df["ids"].str.get_dummies(",")` or can I get similar result using `pd.get_dummies(df, columns=["ids"], dtype=np.uint8)`?

Comment: Actually I ran two results in small set, and they produce totally different results. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: yeah, pd.get_dummies is probably not doing what you want it to do based on the code above.

Comment: this is not a direct answer to your question, but a few thoughts:

1) unlikely, but simple to test if `df["ids"].str.get_dummies(sep=",").astype(np.uint8)` works

2) if each row has only a few elements, a sparse representation will improve memory efficiency significantly (I don't know how to cast this as sparse straight away)

3) `dask` is generally interoperable with pandas but allows out of core (from disk) operations, so memory is not such a constraint

4) you could read/write from csv in chunks; this would be a bit more tedious but almost certainly would work

Comment: I tried that, it first tries to get result using in64 anyways then converts, so still it crashes.

Comment: Can you try `from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer` , `mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)` and then `output = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(mlb.fit_transform(df['ids'].str.split(',')))` this might work as it should save RAM because it returns a sparse matrix

Comment: @anky just running it, still continues, which is a good sign, but can you explain what it does? or shall I assign the result to a variable or something?

Comment: wow, it worked, indeed I should assign it to a variable it looks :)

Comment: @AhmetCetin yes i edited the comment to save it to a variable `output` :) If it works that is because `MultiLabelBinarizer` gives us the option to return a sparse matrix which is condensed. You can check [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix)

Comment: @anky great thanks, one more question if you don't mind. just after that, I want to run ```j = distance.pdist(output, "jaccard")```, using distance function from ```scipy.spatial```, but it also gave memory error, because of the data size and dtype is being still int64. any chance to set at least dtype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For large data it might be a good idea to use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) with `sparse=True` which returns a sparsed matrix , we can then use : [`pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix.html) to convert it back to a dataframe

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)

output = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(mlb.fit_transform(df['ids'].str.split(',')),
                                          columns=mlb.classes_)
```

---

```
print(output)

   1  2  3  4  5
0  1  0  1  1  0
1  1  1  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0  1
3  0  0  1  0  1
```

Comment: great thanks, one more question if you don't mind. just after that, I want to run j = distance.pdist(output, "jaccard"), using distance function from scipy.spatial, but it also gave memory error, because of the data size and dtype is being still int64. any chance to set at least dtype?

Comment: @AhmetCetin not sure but may be we can see if instead of a dataframe we can convert the sparse matrix to an array directly of a smaller bit and use the same. Not much experienced with scipy :)

Comment: in fact I set the result as uint8 using ```output = output.astype(np.uint8)``` but still I get MemoryError